# Installing Debian on an SSD

Tags: debian, system-installation, ssd

Does the Debian installer work out of the box for SSDs? I.e. I heard that you need to align the partitions to 32bit virtual clusters (is it actually true?). Are there any other things I need to take into account while installing Debian on SSD?

I already have some general pointers on running from an SSD: [Optimal SSD configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58761/optimal-ssd-configuration)

In this question I would just like to ask about the actual installation procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you speaking about new generation of SSD that work like Sata-HD?

If yes, the answer to your ask is clearly **Yes, out of the box**!

The procedure is the same as any other disk.

Align to 32 bits?

This *urban legend* came from old **BIOS** who don't know other than HD, floppies, cdrom and so-called Zip-Drive. For booting on this kind of bios with USB devices (removable media bigger than 1,44MB or 2.88MB: Zip Drive geometry permits 100MB or 250MB), As `live USB` has to be installed on `removable media`, a nice script was built for reproduce the crappy geometry of a Zip-Drive.

Understandably, this caused some confusion because the first Live CD always used this script, forcing a bad geometry for *the case when the USB key would be used on a very old bios*. ( But in fact, this is not a *Linux restriction*: Other recent *OS* aren't even able to boot on such very old machines ;-)

Nothing to see with recent Linux using recent SSDs on recent BIOS.

I've personally purchased a 120GB SSD to put in an *old* laptop... The speed is wonderful!

**Note:** As Debian tries to stay essentially useful, minimal installation must be possible on **very old** systems (installation on a 486DX seems always possible, but I'm not sure... I can't do the test. but for the record, my personal web server runs in a VZ container powered by an old Dell laptop with a PIII Copermine @500MHz).

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Debian, but on my Asus eee 901 Linux model I was able to install OpenSuSE 11.1 and 11.2 without any problems or needed any extra options for the SSD.

It worked out of the box for me, and that was a while ago.