# How to get total number of bytes/sectors/blocks written to disk since booting?

Tags: linux, disk

I'm considering and update from HDD to SSD. But since Flash cells can only sustain limited writes. I want to know how much data my computer write during normal operation. So I can determine how long lifetime I can expect from the SSD.

Is it possible to get (rough) numbers somehow?

Comment: Related: [What NOT to put on an SSD?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80864/2465) (and [frostschutz's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80868/2465) in particular).

Answer (score 9):

The first idea I found is the `vmstat -d` command.

It tells you the number of sectors written since booting.

`fdisk -l` will tell you the sector size.

By multiplying the two you can get the number of bytes touched.

It seems my computer does roughly 1 gigabytes worth of writing in two hours. By doing a quick calculation a 128G SSD with 3000 write cycles would last 90 years... Nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 9):

Look at this page http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com.au/2009/02/how-to-measure-and-read-disk-activity.html

```
# cat /sys/block/sda/stat

11836508  1974427 276764974 242202738 13703385 18793696 597760590 2010426698      135 76333414 2253542452
```

Field  3 -- # of sectors read

Field  7 -- # of sectors written

Answer (score 2):

Use [iotop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop) command

You can also use `-a` option to get total bytes write and read per process.

```
iotop -a
```

[image: example]

Comment: This should be `iotop -a` (for `--accumulated`, `-P` means something else)