# Migration from a HDD to a SSD

Tags: linux, backup, ssd, elementary-os, migration

I recently bought a 240GB SSD. Before that, the system (Elementary OS Loki) was installed on a 1TB HDD, consuming 512Gb. My idea would be to leave the user's folder on the HDD, which consumes lots of disk space, and clone only the system folders to the SSD. If this really is not possible, I'd like to know how I can back up and restore programs (.deb packages) from one system to another.

Comment: Anything's possible, but... "only the system to SSD", for regular install, would be something like 10GB on SSD and 230GB free. Not very useful at all... home should be on SSD too https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80868/30851

Comment: Ok. What I mean it's that the biggest files of /home folder must to be in the HDD because it's too big for SSD

Comment: You can create a `data` partition, where you store data files. Then your `/home` directory will be small enough to fit in the SSD either as a directory in the root file system or as a separate `home` partition. The `data` partition can be mounted via a line in `/etc/fstab`. See this link with more details, [Can't see “home” partition in “other locations” - Data partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098164/cant-see-home-partition-in-other-locations/1098211#1098211)